# Convert mathml formulas to PNG or SVG

Tags: epub, conversion, file-format

My ereader does not support mathml formulas. How can I convert all the formulas inside an epub to PNG (or SVG)?

I'm fine with scripts, so it doesn't need to be a software solution.